# Getting: Path must not be null while passing parameters to ItemReader in Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have a spring boot with spring batch application that is giving me below error:

```
8161 [01 Aug 2023 12:25:02.580] ERROR server01 [main] org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep - Encountered an error executing step step in job importUserJob
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.reader' defined in class path resource [com/batch/BatchConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.beanio.spring.BeanIOFlatFileItemReader]: Factory method 'reader' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must not be null
```

**BatchConfiguration.java**

```
    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact> reader(@Value("#{jobParameters['filePath']}") String filePath) {               
        
        BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<Contact> reader = new BeanIOFlatFileItemReader<>();        
        reader.setUseSpringExceptions(true);
        reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));           
        reader.setStreamName(inputContactStreamName);
        reader.setStreamMapping(new ClassPathResource(beanIoConfigurationXmlPath));
        reader.setStreamFactory(StreamFactory.newInstance());
        reader.getLineNumber();
        
        return reader;      
    }
```

Any idea on why that error is coming and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you are passing a `null` `filePath` here:

```
reader.setResource(new FileSystemResource(filePath));
```

Make sure the job parameter is correctly passed to the job.